# In this phrase should I use `have noticed` or `had noticed`?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality

In this phrase, should I use 'have noticed' or 'had noticed'?

> On a road trip, if you see a beautiful tree or a beautiful mountain,
> but you don't know whether your children have noticed it or not...

Comment: I've downvoted this post for lack of research.

Answer (score 2):

Use the present perfect form.  We use the past perfect to refer to an action that happened before another time in the past.

*Example. I asked the kids if they had noticed the beautiful scenery.* That gives you two reference points - did they notice before I asked?

Since there's a connection from the past to the present with the question of the experience of having noticed, use the present perfect (have noticed).